# flutter version conflict with location and firebase_messaging

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am using two plugin with my flutter app `location: ^1.4.1` and `firebase_messaging: ^2.0.0`

If I use single one its works fine but together

```
What went wrong:
Failed to capture snapshot of input files for task ':app:preDebugBuild' property 'compileManifests' during up-to-date check.
> The library com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement is being requested by various other libraries at [[15.0.1,15.0.1]], but resolves to 16.0.1. Disable the plugin and check your dependencies tree using ./gradlew :app:dependencies.
```

1. flutter clean
2. trying to downgrade version for both plugin
3. and google search

non of the above works for me.

app level build: `implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'`

project level build: `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'`

Thanks
:)

Answer (score 0):

In your Project - Goto Android > App > build.gradle

Right after the apply plugin: `'com.google.gms.google-services'` at the bottom of your build.gradle the following can be added to work around the issue.

```
com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesPlugin.config.disableVersionCheck = true
```